# Integrating NFC payments in android application

Tags: android, nfc, hce

Part of the app I am writing needs to allow users to make contactless payments using NFC.

Is it possible to use an existing API to handle the payment and give me back some return information like transaction ID, amount, etc.?

An example would be integrating something like Google Pay, but the documentation doesn't seem to mention NFC.

Tesco's Pay+ allows NFC payments to be made so I assume it must be possible for an app to make contactless payments.

Just hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "existing API"? Which API exactly? Which hardware you are trying to connect to?

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo POS terminals. Essentially the contactless terminals that Google Pay already works with.

Comment: Have you read this https://developers.google.com/pay/api/setup